# Vue - Call beforeMount method from vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

```
I am trying to call `beforemount()` method from "A" file  , this file is imported in another file which is called on homepage that is "B".

I am not sure what i am missing here.
```

Problem is the `beforemount()` method from "A" file is not calling , instead file 
    "B" having same method that is calling into frontend  , seems like component is not getting called in parent file ( also i have before mount in parent ( file B also)
       This is the potential code that i've added in two files , please take a look and let me know

```
         File B

            <script>

            import A from 'one/components/theme/A.vue'

            export default {
              data () {
                return {
                  A
                },
    components: {
        A
      }
              }

            </script>


            FILE A

            <template>
              <div class="A"/>
            </template>

            <script>

            export default {
              name: 'A',
              beforeMount () {
                console.log('segment beforeMount')

              },
            }
```

Comment: at least you are missing the code in your question ;)

Comment: Please check the question again , updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the imported component A inside `compoennts` scope in B and then actually use that component A in the template of B.

FILE B

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <A />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import A from 'one/components/theme/A.vue';
export default {
  components: { A }
}
</script>
```

FILE A stays the same

Comment: Sir , i've done that but before mount method in file "A" is not executing

Comment: Where is the component `Segment` coming from ? You did not import it.
Don't you want to call the `beforeMount` of FILE A? then as answer states, you have to declare A inside the components scope in B. And call A in the templates of B.

Comment: beforeMount is in both file in "B" also and in "A" also "B" is parent , beforeMount in parenr is exexuted but , its not executed in file "A" which is child

Comment: You have to call A from the template of B
In the template of B
```
<template>
<div>
  <A />
</div>
</template>

Also please remove A from the `data()` function in B.

Comment: Removed A from the data() function in B,

Comment: Ok i can see html from "A" is called now , that's great , but beforemount() in Method A is not executing still

Comment: If the HTML is called, then the `beforeMount` should be called to.
HTML is mounted after executing the `beforeMount`

Answer (score 0):

Let's use other naming conventions to explain this, we have ParentComponent.vue and ChildComponent.vue, and the idea is to use ChildComponent.vue in the ParentComponent.vue component:

```
// ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I'm the child component</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "ChildComponent",
    beforeMount () {
     console.log('segment beforeMount in child')
    },
  }
</script>
```

Now let's see the parent component:

```
// ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I'm the {{ message }} component</p>
    <ChildComponent />
  </div>
</template>
import ChildComponent from './routeToChildComponent/ChildComponent.vue'
<script>
  export default {
    name: "ParentComponent",
    // register the components to use
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
    data: () => ({
      message: "Parent"
    }),
    beforeMount () {
     console.log('segment beforeMount in parent')
    },
  }
</script>
```

That way the ParentComponent has access to the child component, and both run the beforeMount Hook.

Comment: I also have beforeMount in parent file also , that is executed currently , after using your code , beforeMount() should be executed twice , thats what i want

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: In your code, You are returning A inside the B's data property, why?

Comment: I have some requirement , thanks for the code & proper syntax , its right code.